# why java 8 use default methods instead of extension methods

Tags: java, java-8

I'm wondering what benefits brings default methods in Java 8 against extension methods or implicit conversion like in Scala? It seems that I couldn't modify existing code with default methods from external library for example and that's weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's purpose is the exact opposite of the use-case you describe. Default methods allow library code to change its API without requiring calling code to be changed & recompiled. It's only a tool to help with API & ABI compatibility, it's not a tool to override implementation details of 3rd party code.

Comment: Thanks. But I couldn't understand a reason for this. Why they restricted with a such small piece of enhancement?

Comment: Well this is not really *explained* anywhere that I know of (at least the initial JSR specs don't expand on any rationale for this behaviour). However I imagine the reason was that this is a much less invasive change when compared with Java 7, and therefore easier to implement & get approval for.